# Flutter firebase OnLaunch Notification Payload Caching

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have successfully setup the Flutter firebase notifications handling, but my problem now is that I need to know what payload was sent with the notification and cache that so that when the App is opened from a terminated state I can retrieved this cached data.

This doesn't seem to work as it always returns a null, and I cannot figure out a way to debug it as its a terminated App state. This happens on both Android and iOS

My setup:

```
_fcm.configure(onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  _handleOnMessage(message);
}, onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  _handleOnLaunch(message);
}, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  _handleOnResume(message);
});
```

Then to store the payload in my cache, so that I can use it for condition logic on startup. I currently use FlutterSecureStorage plugin, but happy to change to any form of storage.

```
void _handleOnLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    _storage.write(key: 'notification_alert', value: message.toString());
}
```

I then try call the cached payload when the app starts up, but it always returns a null.

```
var payload = await _storage.read(key: 'notification_alert');
```